# c# windows form application clear chart and reload error

Tags: c#, charts, reload

I have a c# windows form application.I have 2 charts in my windows form. i also have a combobox and two  buttons among others. What i want is according to the text of the combobox, when i press the start button to load different graphs. So at button start event according to value of combobox i call a different function that loads the charts with what i want each time. And the second button , the stop button has the code below in order to clear the charts.

```
        chart1.Series.Clear();
        chart2.Series.Clear();
```

Sometimes my code runs ok but there are times that it throws the error
" A chart element with the name 'kwh_price' already exists in the 'SeriesCollection'." My code for load the chart is:

```
        string[] seriesArray = { "kwh_price", "p_cost" };
        for (int i = 0; i < seriesArray.Length; i++)
        {
            this.chart1.Series.Add(seriesArray[i]);
            this.chart1.Series[seriesArray[i]].BorderWidth = 7;
        }
```

Am i doing something wrong??is there something more needed in order to clear the chart?? And i don't understand why sometimes it runs ok and others not.

Comment: Why don't you put the clear code in before the load code? That way you can be sure the data is cleared before adding new data. What object type is chart1 / chart2? Is this a 3rd party component or something you have written?

Comment: @LeeWillis i do what u say because in order to be able to press tha start button u have to press the stop button first so i call the clear code first. they are lines and columns

Comment: @LeeWillis but for some reason it did the trick! i tried it about 7 ,8 times and it worked. Although it shouldn't made any difference.i always called the clear code before the load.

Comment: The opposite of Series.Add() is Series.Remove(), not Series.Clear()

Comment: Moved the comment to an answer as it fixed the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the clear code in before the load code. That way you can be sure the data is cleared before adding new data.

```
chart1.Series.Clear();
chart2.Series.Clear();

string[] seriesArray = { "kwh_price", "p_cost" };
        for (int i = 0; i < seriesArray.Length; i++)
        {
            this.chart1.Series.Add(seriesArray[i]);
            this.chart1.Series[seriesArray[i]].BorderWidth = 7;
        }
```